# Can I customize react native joi to return object error

Tags: react-native

Can react native joi return an object error? For example `{fullName: "fullName is required", address: "address is required", mobileNo: "mobileNo is required"};` I only see List of errors

Comment: On your `catch` statement you can check if is an array and join the elements in one error. Or, you can create an specific error object and put all errors in an simple property/variable. Take a look on try/catch.